# Dig command: Is the output guaranteed to be sorted?

Tags: unix, dns, parsing, dig

Let's say I'm trying to lookup the IPs `mail.yahoo.com`, `gmail.com` and `mail.google.com`

If I execute:

```
dig @8.8.8.8 +nocomments +noquestion \
    +noauthority +noadditional +nostats +nocmd \
    gmail.com mail.yahoo.com mail.google.com
```

I get:

```
gmail.com.                       299    IN  A       173.194.123.21
gmail.com.                       299    IN  A       173.194.123.22
mail.yahoo.com.                    0    IN  CNAME   login.yahoo.com.
login.yahoo.com.                   0    IN  CNAME   ats.login.lgg1.b.yahoo.com.
ats.login.lgg1.b.yahoo.com.        0    IN  CNAME   ats.member.g02.yahoodns.net.
ats.member.g02.yahoodns.net.       0    IN  CNAME   any-ats.member.a02.yahoodns.net.
any-ats.member.a02.yahoodns.net.  17    IN  A       98.139.21.169
mail.google.com.                   0    IN  CNAME   googlemail.l.google.com.
googlemail.l.google.com.         243    IN  A       173.194.123.21
googlemail.l.google.com.         243    IN  A       173.194.123.22
```

Can I ensure that if I see a `CNAME` record, the `A` record corresponding to it won't appear before a `CNAME` corresponding to another machine or an `A` record for other hostname?

For instance, let me focus on `mail.yahoo.com` (I just want the IP or IPs `mail.yahoo.com` resolves to):

This is the output:

```
mail.yahoo.com.                    0    IN  CNAME   login.yahoo.com.
login.yahoo.com.                   0    IN  CNAME   ats.login.lgg1.b.yahoo.com.
ats.login.lgg1.b.yahoo.com.        0    IN  CNAME   ats.member.g02.yahoodns.net.
ats.member.g02.yahoodns.net.       0    IN  CNAME   any-ats.member.a02.yahoodns.net.
any-ats.member.a02.yahoodns.net.  17    IN  A       98.139.21.169
```

The hostname I'm looking for ( `mail.yahoo.com`) is the first column of the first entry. Then there's a bunch of `CNAMES` I really don't care about, and then an `A` record with the actual IP (which I do care about).

Is there a possibility of getting the `CNAMES` or `A` records out of order? Something like:

```
ats.login.lgg1.b.yahoo.com.        0    IN  CNAME   ats.member.g02.yahoodns.net. #(!)BAD
ats.member.g02.yahoodns.net.       0    IN  CNAME   any-ats.member.a02.yahoodns.net. #(!)BAD
mail.yahoo.com.                    0    IN  CNAME   login.yahoo.com.
login.yahoo.com.                   0    IN  CNAME   ats.login.lgg1.b.yahoo.com.
any-ats.member.a02.yahoodns.net.  17    IN  A       98.139.21.169
```

Or even worse (the actual `A` record on top):

```
any-ats.member.a02.yahoodns.net.  17    IN  A       98.139.21.169
mail.yahoo.com.                    0    IN  CNAME   login.yahoo.com.
login.yahoo.com.                   0    IN  CNAME   ats.login.lgg1.b.yahoo.com.
ats.login.lgg1.b.yahoo.com.        0    IN  CNAME   ats.member.g02.yahoodns.net.
ats.member.g02.yahoodns.net.       0    IN  CNAME   any-ats.member.a02.yahoodns.net.
```

Or the worse of the worse (in a multi-resolution `dig` execution, as the one shown on top of the post):

```
ats.member.g02.yahoodns.net.       0    IN  CNAME   any-ats.member.a02.yahoodns.net.
any-ats.member.a02.yahoodns.net.  17    IN  A       98.139.21.169
mail.google.com.                   0    IN  CNAME   googlemail.l.google.com.  # This one I want
gmail.com.                       299    IN  A       173.194.123.21            # This one I want
gmail.com.                       299    IN  A       173.194.123.22            # This one I want
mail.yahoo.com.                    0    IN  CNAME   login.yahoo.com.          # This one I want
login.yahoo.com.                   0    IN  CNAME   ats.login.lgg1.b.yahoo.com.
ats.login.lgg1.b.yahoo.com.        0    IN  CNAME   ats.member.g02.yahoodns.net.
googlemail.l.google.com.         243    IN  A       173.194.123.21
googlemail.l.google.com.         243    IN  A       173.194.123.22
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No - the order of the returned result is up to the DNS server, and you don't have control over that, so I would not depend on the order from a particular DNS server.

I do believe and my tests so far have confirmed this, that the actual queries are done in order, in your case, first google.com, and last mail.google.com - that is because dig will run the queries in the order you specify on the command line.

Because of how the command line syntax is setup, the order is important. Thus my answer. If it didn't approach them in the order specified any non-global modifiers would get screwed up.

From the man page:

> The BIND 9 implementation of dig supports specifying multiple queries
>   on the command line (in addition to supporting the -f batch file
>   option). Each of those queries can be supplied with its own set of
>   flags, options and query options.
>
> In this case, each query argument represent an individual query in the
>   command-line syntax described above. Each consists of any of the
>   standard options and flags, the name to be looked up, an optional
>   query type and class and any query options that should be applied to
>   that query.